# Insert random letters and letters of string in a table just like in wordsearch

Tags: php, arrays, tcpdf

this codes is for displaying random letters with a table like in a word search game. The problem is,.I can't insert strings in the table,. what if I have array of strings,. eg., sample, them, power, some. How can I insert these strings in the cell?

I am creating something like this http://children.pfcblogs.com/learn/word-search-test/

```
    $row = 10;
    $col = 10;

    $w = 8;
    $h = 8;

    for ($r=1;$r<=$row;$r++) {

         for ($c=1;$c<=$col;$c++) {

              $pdf->Cell($w,$h,$str= array_merge(range('A','Z'))[mt_rand(1,24)],1,0,'C');

         }

         $pdf->Ln($h);
     }
```

Comment: why are you calling array_merge? (what I mean is range is already returning an array and calling array_merge on a single array doesn't do anything) and you never use the variable $characters or #max anywhere as far as I can tell. Is there more code?

Comment: Also, what error or undesired behavior are you getting?

Comment: there is no error in that code, the problem is that, I need to insert the letters of string.

Comment: Oppps..sorry PLEASE DISREGARD the variable $max and $character

Comment: when I removed the array_merge,. I'm getting error,. but no error when it has array_merge. so no prob with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way above and beyond for stackoverflow, but I'm in a good mood. :-)

So this takes a string of words (you can add more) separated by comas and splits those in to an array and then finds words that will fit until it gets down to 1 letter then it just uses the random letters from before to fill the space.

This is far from perfect one thing you'd see is all of the lines will start with words and end with random letters. Also, the words are only horizontal not vertical. Building matrixes of words horizontal, vertical, and diagonal gets pretty complex and is certainly beyond the scope of this site.

Here is the code as it stands. It's a good start.

```
$row = 10;
$col = 10;

$w = 8;
$h = 8;
$characters = range('A','Z');

$words="in, on, it, up, at, am, of, and, band, banned, bland, brand, brande, canned, chand, fanned, gland, grand, grande, hand, land, lande, mande, manned, panned, planned, rand, sande, scanned, shand, spanned, stand, strand, strande, tanned, vande, zand";

$wordList = explode(",",$words);
$myWord="";

$max = count($characters) - 1;  
for ($r=1;$r<=$row;$r++) {
    for ($c=1;$c<=$col;$c++) {
        //if we have more than 1 space
        //(enough room for a 2 or more letter word)
        $maxWordLength=$col-$c+1;
        if($maxWordLength > 1){
            //get a word if we need a new one
            if(empty($myWord)){
                $wordLen=99;
                while($wordLen > $maxWordLength){
                    $myWord=trim(strToUpper($wordList[mt_rand(0,count($wordList))]));
                    $wordLen=strlen($myWord);
                }
            }
            //get the next letter of the word we're using
            $thisChar=substr($myWord,0,1);
            $myWord=substr($myWord,1);
        }else{
            //if we don't have room for a word put a random letter
            $thisChar=$characters[mt_rand(0,$max)];
        }


        $pdf->Cell($w,$h,$thisChar,1,0,'C');

        //for debugging (remove this)
        echo($thisChar.' ');

    }
    $pdf->Ln($h);

    //for debugging remove this
    echo('<hr>');
}
```

Also, here is a link to an existing open source PHP solution that is along the lines of what you're looking for. I downloaded it and took a peek and it's about 3000 lines of code. So as I said well beyond the scope of stack overflow.

http://fswordfinder.sourceforge.net/

Comment: wait i'l test this :)

Comment: Hi I tested your codes, and it had a little bug, it does produced two to three blank box. I tested this with only 4 words. but thx. I'll just try to play with your codes thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
$row = 10;
$col = 10;

$w = 8;
$h = 8;

$characters = range('A','Z');
$max = count($characters) - 1;  

for ($r=1;$r<=$row;$r++) {
    for ($c=1;$c<=$col;$c++) {
        $pdf->Cell($w,$h,$characters[mt_rand(0,$max)],1,0,'C');

        //for debugging (remove this)
        echo("$w,$h,{$characters[mt_rand(0,$max)]},1,0,'C'");
        echo('<br>');
    }
    $pdf->Ln($h);
}
```

I added in the echo code to see what it's doing since I don't have the PDF library that you are using so I couldn't test that but the echo output was like this so assuming the pdf cell method is set up correctly it should work.

```
8,8,D,1,0,'C'
8,8,S,1,0,'C'
8,8,C,1,0,'C'
8,8,C,1,0,'C'
8,8,F,1,0,'C'
8,8,Q,1,0,'C'
8,8,B,1,0,'C'
8,8,H,1,0,'C'
8,8,C,1,0,'C'
8,8,N,1,0,'C'
8,8,A,1,0,'C'
8,8,H,1,0,'C'
8,8,Y,1,0,'C'
8,8,T,1,0,'C'
8,8,B,1,0,'C'
8,8,V,1,0,'C'
8,8,Y,1,0,'C'
...
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for revising my codes, your codes has the same output as mine. So how can you enter a string here together with the random letters? for example,. there, data, what, somehow.

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean. You'd probably want a dictionary file or something, but you could do it with an array of words. They wouldn't be random letters anymore though. I'll submit again in a second.

Comment: @user2901740 Just added another answer with code along the lines of what you want and a link to a full solution. If this answers your questions please mark it as such. Thanks.